# How to download a file in multiple thread and merge all segments?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

I created an application to download a file from URL.

When I press start it will create one thread to download that file.

OK.

Now I want many thread to download same file in different segments and then merge all downloaded segment to get original file.

How to do that?

Comment: What's giving you trouble? Building the thread pool? Downloading a byte range instead of a complete file? Recombining pieces of a file?

Comment: Downloading a byte range instead of a complete file?  How?

Comment: Is this to speed up the download?  If so, I think the speed will depend more on the bandwidth of the end user's machine, than the number of threads used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at page 127: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt. You can set the request property as described here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

You may want look up the HTTP [`Accept-Ranges`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5) header definitions. Then you basically start multiple threads downloading parts of the file and merge them afterwards.